# negative lookahead of special combination of characters in RegEx

Tags: regex, sas

I am trying to add `\s+` around special characters, except for `<<` or `>>`. For example `<< ) < <? ?` should become `<< \s+)\s+ \s+<\s+ \s+<?\s+ \s+?\s+`

I am using `^[\w\s]+` to capture non-word character except whitespaces but I dont seem to be able to get the negative lookahed to work. Any help?

This is what i am trying in SAS:

```
Data _NULL_;
a = prxchange("s/(?!(<<|>>)(^[\w\s]+)/\s*$1\s*/", -1,"<< ) < <? ?");
putlog a;
run;
```

Comment: Try `"s/(?<!\S)(?!(?:<<|>>)(?!\S))([^\w\s]+)(?!\S)/\s+$1\s+/"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's exactly what i was looking for.  Could you explain how it works and post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
"s/(?<!\S)(?!(?:<<|>>)(?!\S))([^\w\s]+)(?!\S)/\s+$1\s+/"
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<!\S)` - a left-hand side whitespace boundary
- `(?!(?:<<|>>)(?!\S))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right, there is `<<` or `>>` followed with a whitespace boundary
- `([^\w\s]+)` - one or more chars other than word  and whitespace chars
- `(?!\S)` - a right-hand whitespace boundary.